# aws fargate adding a parameter for environment variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to automate the Cloudformation deployment of our fargate instances. I have cloudformation deploying successfully if i hard the environment variables entries but if i try to add as parameters, type string, it complains about it not being a string.

here is the parameter

"EnvVariables": {
  "Description": "All environment Variables for Docker to run",
  "Type": "String"
 },

In my task definition i have the following settings for the Container Definition

```
     "Environment": [
      {
        "Name": "JAVA_OPTS",
        "Value": "-Djdbc.url=jdbc:dbdriver://xxxx.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com:xxxx/xxxxxxxxx -Djdbc.user=xxxxx -Djdbc.password=xxxxx" 
      }
    ]
```

If i enter the following into the parameter field via the gui

```
"-Djdbc.url=jdbc:dbdriver://xxxx.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com:xxxx/xxxxxxxxx -Djdbc.user=xxxxx -Djdbc.password=xxxxx"
```

it complains about it not being a string.

How do i edit this to be accepted as a parameter?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using the task definition (portal or JSON) you can define `"secrets"` inside the `"containerDefinitions"` section which will be retrieved from secrets manager.

> Note: At the time of writing, Fargate only supports secrets that are a single value, not the JSON or key value secrets. So choose OTHER when creating the secret and just put a single text value there.

```
{ 
    "ipcMode": null,
    "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::##:role/roleName",
    "containerDefinitions": [
      {
         ...
        "secrets": [{
          "name": "SomeEnvVariable",
          "valueFrom": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:region:###:secret:service/secretname"
        }],
        ...
     }
    ],
    "requiresCompatibilities": [
      "FARGATE"
    ],
    "networkMode": "awsvpc",
    ...
}
```

Note: that execution role defined in the task needs a policy attached such as `SecretsManagerReadWrite`

[More info in docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/specifying-sensitive-data-secrets.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can inject dynamic environment variables. Even if it's possible, please refrain from putting password in clear text.

What I did is to store the values in secured SSM param. Then, java code can fetch values and initialise accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I got around this by using a Jinja2 Python template script and inserted the env variables using

```
"Environment": [
    {% for environment in td.envVariables %}
    {
      "Name": "{{environment.name}}",
      "Value": "{{environment.value}}"
    },
    {% endfor %}
```

This then enabled an array of env variables to be applied. The script cannot be applied directly as a cloudformation script but instead needs to be included within another shell/python script.